# Make a single request containing many requests to eBay API

Tags: ebay-api

I send a request to eBay API to get my eBay buying. I also want to get some extra information about each item, let's say that's `itemCondition` and `itemCategory` (parent and child). `GetMyeBayBuyingResponse` doesn't contain these fields. So I have to call `GetItemRequest` **for each returned item** to get them.

But it's very bad, it would take much more traffic and time. Is there any more efficient way do it?

I also read somewhere at eBay that there was a kind of ability to pack many requests to one request and then send it to reduce traffic and effort. Is it true?

**P.S.** Note that I'm not asking about `itemCondition` and `itemCategory` fields only. There might be any other fields. The goal is make **only one** request containing many calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are calls with item data:

- If you're the seller of the items, ebay proposes to use **[GetSellerList](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/GetItem.html)**.
- If you want all items you recently bid on / bought, you can use **[GetBidderList](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/GetBidderList.html)**.

For sellers with many products, ebay offers [LMS (Marge Merchant Services)](https://www.x.com/developers/ebay/products/large-merchant-services), but i thinks this is mostly applicable for sellers, I think there are no calls to retrieve bought items.